# Time Series Analysis in R Using ARIMA model on loop to get the optimal model

Tags: r, loops, time-series, forecast

i've been working on this program to get the optimal ARIMA model for my time series data points. 
I created a loop in which the different models can be evaluated by replacing the value of parameters on the arima() function with the for () loop value replacing the parameter with the value of the loop variable.

This is with the purpose to get the arima model with the minimum AIC or BIC. The model starts running fine, but when i leave it for a while, it displays this error, and i don't know what it means.

i'll leave the code and the error...

Thanks for your help, hope someone can help me! :)

```
    minimo<-5000
    prueba<-0
    arima_1<-auto.arima(ts_m_rojo)
    for (p in 0:3) {
      for (d in 0:3) {
        for (q in 0:3) {
          for (P in 0:1) {
            for (D in 0:1) {
              for (Q in 0:1) {
          for (l in 7:7) {
              prueba<-arima_1$aic
            if (minimo>prueba) {
              minimo<-prueba
              print(paste("ARIMA(",p,",",d,",",q,")",",","      (",P,",",D,",",Q,")","[",l,"]"))
          print(arima_1)
          acf(arima_1$residuals, xaxp = c(0, 120, 4), lag.max=120, main = "") 
          pacf(arima_1$residuals, xaxp = c(0, 120, 4), lag.max=120, main = "")
          }
arima_1 <- arima (ts_m_rojo, order=c(p,d,q) , 
                  seasonal= list(order=c (P,D, Q) ,period=l))
      }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


    Error in optim(init[mask], armafn, method = optim.method, hessian =            TRUE,  : 
    non-finite finite-difference value [1]
    In addition: Warning message:
    In log(s2) : NaNs produced
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Not an answer to your question, but an hint: have you seen [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.4/topics/auto.arima)? Maybe it could help.